# Lubuntu LiveUSB made with UNetbootin not bootable

Tags: liveusb, unetbootin

I tried to make a Lubuntu 13.04 LiveUSB with UNetbootin (Mac version), but it is not bootable. Not on the PC I want to boot it, and not on the Mac I made the drive with (On Mac it just doesn't show up in the bootable drives menu (alt during startup) and on the PC I want to boot it it says "Missing operating system"). The drive is formatted as FAT (via Disk Utility).

What is going wrong?

Comment: I did it with the Windows version now and it worked. But it would be nice if I could do it with my Mac too...

Answer (score 0):

Try booting another version of ubuntu like 12.10 or 04,Or you may install it via LiveUSB windows version

Comment: 12.04 didn't work either